# recNecessary and sufficient conditions for $rank\left(A+B\right)=rank\left(A\right)+rank\left(B\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

In Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson, the following condition is given:
$range\left(A\right) \bigcap range\left(B\right) = \left\{0\right\}$ and $range\left(A^T\right) \bigcap range\left(B^T\right) = \left\{0\right\}$
I am trying to find a proof but no luck.

One direction is easy:
$range\left(A+B\right) \subseteq range\left(A\right) + range\left(B\right)$
implies
$rank\left(A+B\right) \le rank\left(A\right) + rank\left(B\right) -  dim\left(range\left(A\right) \bigcap range\left(B\right)\right)$.
If rank is additive, we have $range\left(A\right) \bigcap range\left(B\right) = \left\{0\right\}$. Taking transpose leads to $range\left(A^T\right) \bigcap range\left(B^T\right) = \left\{0\right\}$.